# UILabelの数に応じてUIView、UIScrollViewの長さを変更する方法は？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, iphone

UIViewにUILabelを複数個追加し、そのUILabelの個数に応じてUIViewの大きさを変え、さらにUIScrollViewに乗せ、ScrollViewをUIViewの大きさに応じて変えたいです。
また、UILabelの個数が30個を超えた場合は31個目以降を2つ目のUIViewに貼り付けし、
ボタンを押すことでページが切り替わるような仕様にしたいです。

UIViewとUIScrollViewの長さを自動で変える方法に「sizeToFit()」があることはわかるのですが、
今のコードでは可変になりません。
どう書けば良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

        var tokyoCount = 0
        var tokyoArray = [0]

        // CSV読み込み
        if let csvPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mise", ofType: "csv") {
            do {
                var csvString =  try NSString(contentsOfFile: csvPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String
                csvString = csvString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")
                let array2:Array = csvString.components(separatedBy: ",")

                var items2 = [String]()
                array2.enumerated().forEach { (index, value) in

                    items2.append(value)

                    if value.range(of:string) != nil{
                        print("exists")

                        tokyoArray.append(tokyoCount)
                    }

                    if (index + 1) % 6 == 0 {

                        str2.append(items2)
                        items2 = [String]()

                        tokyoCount += 1

                    }

                }
            } catch {
                // エラー
            }
        }


        // ScrollViewを生成.
        myScrollView = UIScrollView()
        myScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 300, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        let myImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.frame = myScrollView.frame
        myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        myScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
        myScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        myScrollView.alpha = 0.3

        // Labelを作成.
        let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 200, height: 30))
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.text = "店舗一覧"
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        let v:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1.0, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1.0);

        for var i in 1...tokyoArray.count-1{

            //店名
            let nameLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10+(i*100), width: 250, height: 50))
            nameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            nameLabel.tag = i
            nameLabel.text = str2[tokyoArray[i]][0]
            nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
            myScrollView.addSubview(nameLabel)

            //住所
            let addressLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 50+(i*100), width: 250, height: 50))
            addressLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            addressLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            addressLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            addressLabel.tag = i
            addressLabel.text = str2[tokyoArray[i]][1]
            addressLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
            myScrollView.addSubview(addressLabel)


        }

        v.sizeToFit()
        myScrollView.sizeToFit()
        myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:300, height:myScrollView.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(myScrollView)

   }
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/52541

Comment: 質問者さんのやりたいことが、正確に把握できないのですが、Scroll Viewのサイズを変更したいのでしょうか、それともScroll View内のContent Viewのサイズを変更したいのでしょうか？後者なら、LabelなどのSubviewの大きさとマージンなどを積算していって、Scroll Viewのプロパティ`contentSize`を決定することで、実現できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事解決しました。